# $\liminf (a_n-b_n)=\liminf a_n-\limsup b_n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can you say me if and why

$\liminf (a_n-b_n)=\liminf a_n-\limsup b_n$?

I do not know how I can prove that or if I wrote it dowm correctly.

---

**Edit**

In a proof I found the following:

$$
\liminf\int (2g-h_n)\, d\mu=\int 2g\, d\mu-\limsup\int h_n\, d\mu
$$

Where does the $\limsup$ come from?

Comment: This is not correct.

Comment: This is not correct. Consider $a_n = (-1)^n, b_n = (-1)^{n+1}$. Use this to try to see what goes wrong. If you want more help, give background to where you found this and what you've tried.

Comment: I will make my question more precisely.

Comment: In response to the edit:

I assume that the $\liminf$ is being taken over $n$. Thus, the first term is a constant and differs from your original post. 

However, we always have that 
$$ \liminf a_n = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \inf_{k \ge n} a_k =  - \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sup_{k \ge n} a_k = - \limsup a_n.$$

Comment: But why then $-\limsup$ in my edit?

Comment: Why not $\int 2g\, d\mu-\liminf_n\int h_n\, d\mu$?

Answer (score 3):

Let $a_n = b_n = (-1)^n$. Then $\liminf_n (a_n-b_n) = 0$, $\liminf_n a_n = -1$, $\limsup_n b_n = 1$, but $\liminf_n (a_n-b_n)  \neq \liminf_n a_n - \limsup_n b_n$.

However, if $a_n \to a$, then we have equality because
$\liminf_n (a_n -b_n) = a+\liminf_n (-b_n) = a- \limsup b_n$.

To see this, suppose for some $\epsilon>0$, we have some $N$ such that $a-\epsilon \le a_k \le a+ \epsilon$ for $k \ge N$. Then
$a-b_k -\epsilon \le a_k-b_k \le a -b_k + \epsilon$, and so
\begin{eqnarray}
\inf_{k \ge N} (a-b_k) -\epsilon &=& a+\inf_{k \ge N} (-b_k) -\epsilon \\
&\le& \inf_{k \ge N}(a_k-b_k) \\
&\le& \inf_{k \ge N} (a -b_k) + \epsilon \\
&=&  a+\inf_{k \ge N} (-b_k) +\epsilon
\end{eqnarray}
Since $a_n \to a$, we obtain the desired result.